# Compiled php5.3.8 extension with VC++ 2008, works on the computer it was compiled on, but doesn't work if transferred to another system

Tags: php, php-extension

I got compile php 5.3.8 extension DLL  with VS++2008 on my laptop running wamp-server 2.2 .But when I copy the DLL to a work another computer it can't runing. Does the DLL only work on the computer you compile it on ? any idea ? thanks...

Comment: Do you reference other libraries from yours? If yes, are they on the other computer available?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check for missing dependencies.
My bets are on the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5582) package:

> The Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) installs runtime components of Visual C++ Libraries required to run applications developed with Visual C++ SP1 on a computer that does not have Visual C++ 2008 SP1 installed.

Comment: thanks it runing with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)